# Why does BIGINT/INT not work in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

In Netezza, when I query

```
SELECT 2147483648:: BIGINT
```

I get the result 2147483647 - which is one less than the number I put in.

When I query

```
SELECT 2147483648:: INTEGER
```

I get "ERROR:  pg_atoi: error reading "2147483648": Numerical result out of range"

Why is that?

Comment: I don't have Netezza on hand, but the two versions work in Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CAST to a BIGINT for that value should work just fine:

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> SELECT 2147483648::BIGINT;
  ?COLUMN?  
------------
 2147483648
(1 row)
```

The CAST to an integer fails because the value 2,147,483,648 is outside the bounds allowed for the INTEGER data type  ( -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647), [which is documented here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_data_types_exact_numeric.html).

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> SELECT 2147483648::INTEGER;
ERROR:  pg_atoi: error reading "2147483648": Numerical result out of range
```

Comment: I should have paid more attention to datatype documentation for INTEGERs. However, BIGINT is still not working....

Comment: Provide select VERSION() and show is the actual output of that and your CAST to BIGINT

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "select VERSION()" so I'm assuming I am suppose to type "SELECT VERSION(2147483648)"? If so, I am getting an error: 

"ERROR:  Function 'VERSION(INT8)' does not exist
Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types
You may need to add explicit typecasts"

Thank you by the way for your help!

Comment: I mean "SELECT VERSION();" and shows the output of that.

Comment: Output is: Release 7.2.0.6-P1 [Build 46376]

Comment: You are on a relatively recent release, so there should be no issue.  If you don't get the same result that I posted here then you should open a ticket with support.